# How to access an array of objects with return type UIViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, casting

I have created tab bar controller programatically which has an array of viewcontroller having instance of RedViewController

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let tab1 = Red()
    let tab1BarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab1", image:UIImage(named:"bell-off-7.png"), selectedImage:UIImage(named:"bell-7.png") )
    tab1BarItem.tag = 0
    tab1.tabBarItem = tab1BarItem


    let tab2 = ObserverViewController()
    let tab2BarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab2", image: UIImage(named:"bell-off-7.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named:"bell-7.png"))
    tab2BarItem.tag = 1
    tab2.tabBarItem = tab2BarItem

    self.viewControllers = [tab1,tab2]
}
}
```

How can i use the instance of class Red to access a property of it as Array viewController is of UIViewController return type

Comment: FYI - all of the code you have in `viewWillAppear` should be in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Where do you need to access the properties of the `Red` view controller? And that is a terrible name for the class. It should be something like `RedViewController`, not just `Red`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to cast the `UIViewController` to `Red` after retrieving it from the array.

`guard let redController = self.viewController.first as? Red else {return}`

This way, the type of `redController` is `Red`. When storing subclasses of a certain class in a collection whose type is the superclass, type information is never lost, so you can access the specific subclass properties after casting the specific array element to the subclass it is from.